# how to stop jquery .load to overwrite information inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jquery .load function to load a divs(left) from a other page inside a div(page_content) on the current page but when i use the load function to load a other div(right) in page_content it overwrites everyting inside the div(page_content).
And i just want it to be added to the div.

here is my code:

`function load(){
    $('#page_content').load('test.php .left');}`

`function load2(){
$('#page_content').load('test2.php .right');
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `callback function to convert two call to single call and get the .left and right content in the call to assign to your element with id page_content`,

```
$('#page_content').load('test.php', function(result){
  leftContent = $(result).find('.left').html();
  leftRight = $(result).find('.right').html();
  $(this).html($(leftContent + leftRight ).find('')
});
```

Comment: +1. This is a much better solution than mine since it only needs one remote call. :)

Comment: Thanks @Anders Holmström, so nice of you.

Comment: i have tried your code but it loads all divs inside the file and instantly removes them afterwards

Comment: hide page_content in start of load and show it again. $(this).hide() will be first statement and $(this).show() will be last.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
function load(){ $('#page_content').load('test.php .left');}

$.ajax({
  url: 'test2.php .right',
  success: function(data) {
     $('#page_content').append(data);
  }
});
```